# ASP.NET Core Identity change login URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and I used scaffolding to add Identity, which is working OK Except that when I try to go to a page that requires login, it takes me to:
`/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl`

How do I change it to go to just /Account/Login which is my own login page i created.

I tried this:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                });
```

but it still goes to /Identity/

Comment: for core 3.1 it's a different answer...i ended up here because i searched with 'asp.net core' term on google without specific version; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525775/change-identity-login-url-in-asp-net-core-3-0

Answer (score 18):

I just ran into this same issue.  I resolved it by moving my

`services.ConfigureApplicationCookie` call to after my `services.AddIdentity` call in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: services.ConfigureApplicationCookie should be after services.AddIdentity, thanks!

Comment: you are the man. Just wondering, how do people figure out the stuff like this? looking through .NET sources?

Answer (score 15):

Try adding `new PathString("...")` and setting the route in the controller.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(720);
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Account")]
public class SecurityController : Controller
{
    [Route("Login/{returnUrl?}")]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried both changes and it still returns to identity/account/login =/

Comment: I got around this for the time being by having my identity/account/login page redirect to /account/login but if you have any other ideas on how to properly fix that, I'd rather not leave that redirect in the project

Answer (score 9):

Check how you register Identity service if you have:

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => { })
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

replace it with

`services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => { })
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

and keep your code in the `ConfigureApplicationCookie` that worked in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Move services.ConfigureApplicationCookie after services.AddIdentity and most important remove AddDefaultUI in services. Reference [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5828)

Comment: Yes, the order is what was my problem, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = x =>
                    {
                        x.Response.Redirect("Account/Login");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };

            });
```