# Change identity login URL in ASP.net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to change the default login URL from:

```
 /Identity/Account/Login
```

to

```
/Login
```

I've looked up similar questions and they came up with a solution similar to this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CompanyLoginContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<CompanyLoginUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
       .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CompanyLoginContext>()
       .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Logout");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessDenied");

        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    }); 
}
```

But somehow this isn't working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be sure that you have scalffolded Identity,you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Then you need to modify `Identity/Account/Login.cshtml` like below:

```
@page "/Login"
```

Comment: Thank you for this working answer , but how did you get to this solution?

Comment: I have met the similar problem like yours before.

Comment: Where are you supposed to put that?

Comment: @ScottWilson,What?I have clearly said just modify `Identity/Account/Login.cshtml`.

Comment: @Rena I'm not using any of the automatically generated views though. I don't get why you can't just specify in startup where you want the sign in page.

Comment: Hi @ScottWilson,you may misunderstand op's question.Yes you could just sprcify the startup to where you want to sign in.But the default Identity login url is `Identity/Account/Login` not `Login`.You must have `Login` page with `Login` url,then waht you said should work.

Comment: @Rena for some reason when I try to modify in startup to this: options.LoginPath = new PathString("/signin"); it just keeps trying to redirect to the default.  I just gave up and put a controller action at the default path and just redirect to the action I want to use. So frustrating they make it this difficult to override.

Comment: Started yet another project and still this same problem again, such a crap framework.